# report builder select statement with parameter LOV list (with multiples entries)

Tags: sql, oracle, parameters

i have made a parameter in oracle report builder (p_user) wich can return a list with multiple users.

How can i use this in my select statement to optain the correct list?

I have now:

select note,user,dep_name,dep_id
from departement_notes
where user=:p_user

For now if i select 1 user it will show all notes from this user. When i select multiple users it will show nothing as the 'user' does not match the p_user value.

Example;

if the paramater 'p_user'= AR then the list shows everything for user AR
when the parameter 'p_user'= AR,CZ,GD then nothing is shown

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to parametrize the `IN` clause, so that it would be `user in (:p_user)` where p_user is comma-separated list. Unfortunately, it's impossible. There are ways around it, though, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterize-an-sql-in-clause) for example.
In your case, it would look like that:

```
select note,user,dep_name,dep_id 
  from departement_notes    
 WHERE ','||:p_user||',' LIKE '%,'||user||',%'
```

This way, you search for string `,(username),` in the string `,AR,CZ,GD,`. Commas are necessary so that you wouldn't match username `A`. Keep in mind that this approach does not allow you to use indexes on `user` column, so use carefully. There's another approach described [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/aramamoo/entry/how_to_split_comma_separated_string_and_pass_to_in_clause_of_select_statement).